# Can we pass @Query (value="Dyanically read from some properties file") dynamically in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can we pass @Query (value="Dynamically read from some properties file") dynamically in Spring JPA. Or apart from using @NamedQuery and using xml files is there a way we can externalize the queries ?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try doing like this
@Query (value="${some_value_from_property_file}")

Comment: yeah it is just assuming everything under quotes as query and query is failing

Answer (score 1):

1. Under `resources` folder create file `jpa-named-queries.properties`
2. Add your Query in the `jpa-named-queries.properties` file. query name format is `Schema_class_name.method_name`. In this bellow example the query returns `Account` entity class, hence first part is Account. After the dot add the method name(you can name anything, just make sure in the repository class the method name matches)

```
Account.LoginQuery=SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.username = :param or a.email=:param
```

3. Add the method to the repository class `AccountRepositoy`

```
Account LoginQuery(String param);
```

Now from service you can call this method just like other jpa methods.

Comment: mahfuj asif Can you provide one small example for this. For me also this requirement needed.

Comment: @KOUSIKdaniel i have updated my answer. I have already provided an example though. If still you are confused let me know. and if the answer helps dont forget to upvote

Comment: @mahuj asif I am facing No property loginQuery found for type error.
What about the native query? How do i use it from Property file?

Comment: @KOUSIKdaniel seems like you might save some type. You can ask this in SO with proper details and tag me/give link so that i can see details and help

Comment: I can able to run the basic query using your example. but i need help for nativeQuery
for example:@Query(value = "******",nativeQuery = true) inside the JpaRepository interface

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662990/4533050
this link helped me Thank you for your answer

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
@Value( "${example.query1}" )
private String query1;

@Query(value = query1)
someMethod();
```

Comment: Yeah but i am using interface implementing JPARepository so i cannot assign value like you stated.

Comment: Hum, you right. I have searched here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) and I don't think you can do that with a JPA repository...maybe create a JdbcTemplate and run the query though there