# Get query from file in SPRING BOOT using @Query

Tags: java, spring, oracle, yaml

I have a proyect that use to load queries this:

```
@Query(value = SELECT_BY_USER_ID, nativeQuery = true)
Employee findByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

On "SELECT_BY_USER_ID" is a normal String query.

I have a YML configuration outside jar, that I use to load differents configurations, and I want to use this YML, to load queries too.

Example YML:

```
file:
    query1: SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

But I don't know how to load directly from my file in @Query value, I tried like that:

```
@Query(value = ("${file.query1}"), nativeQuery = true)
List<Employee> findByCost();
```

How can I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to load SQL from resources folder, you can try [spring-data-sqlfile](https://github.com/VEINHORN/spring-data-sqlfile) library. It supports loading SQL queries from resources. So you just need to put your SQL queries to the resources folder and than you can reference them in SqlFromResource annotation:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @SqlFromResource(path = "select_user_by_id.sql")
    User findById(int userId);
}
```

The output will be like:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepositoryGenerated extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {    
  @Query(
      value = "SELECT *     FROM users     WHERE id = :userId",
      nativeQuery = true
  )
  User findById(int userId);
}
```

Comment: Is this a tested library? Is it actively used in the community?

Comment: @geneb. its not actively used by community for now.

Comment: But it's a JPA repository

Comment: nice library, but you should definitely disclose that you're the author...

Answer (score 6):

Configured queries cannot be loaded from YML, as far as I know. They can be loaded from another file. Create a file in your resource project folder named `/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties` and then place your query:

```
Employee.findById=select * from Employee e where e.id=?1
```

and then call your query:

```
@Query(name = "Employee.findById")
Employee findByUserId(String id);
```

Comment: And If I want to call outisde resources folder? I mean, outside jar.

Comment: Then you should set your query in a property and use a repository with JPA `EntityManager`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, spring data doesn't seem to support direct properties reference withing @Query anno (like in @Value).
 Despite that and assuming you use spring-data-jpa and Hibernate it is possible to use an external .xml file to store your queries as named queries and refer to them by method name, or like

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, name="Repository1.query1")
```

This is a nice article on this matter : [JPA Queries in XML File](https://hajba.hu/2016/06/21/jpa-queries-in-xml-files/) and it describes how to place your .xml file elsewhere than the expected orm.xml

Comment: Hello. Please review your answer: The provided link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mirage-sql library [Here](https://github.com/mirage-sql/mirage) .It's really great. You can easily pass the Java parameter to the sql file, or pass a dynamic sql string from java code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31120503)