# Spring JPA Query annotation - input a sql file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Can we pass or input a .sql file to the Query annotation in Spring JPA?

Something like this
@Query(**file:/sql/employeeList.sql** , nativeQuery=true)

/sql/employeeList.sql - i would like to put this file somewhere in the code, which will have the select sql in it.

I am not looking to have native sql string 
@Query("select abc....", nativeQuery=true) -- I dont want to use like this. because my sql is too huge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get query from file in SPRING BOOT using @Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661804/get-query-from-file-in-spring-boot-using-query)

Comment: Seems like they are looking for the same in the above given link. but VEINHORN/spring-data-sqlfile is not spring provided libraries. I cannot use github libraries in office projects.

Comment: @jens-schauder normally you cannot use a resource file on `@Query` annotation but you can check this [repo](https://github.com/mcanatalay/spring-jpa-resource-query). You can just create your own JpaQueryMethodFactory that provides your own version of `JpaQueryMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

@Jens Schauder is right you can't specify a sql file in Spring Data Jpa but as an alternative solution you could use this library https://github.com/VEINHORN/spring-data-sqlfile or you could simply load the file on your own.
**Note:** im using lombok on this example

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ArticleBatchRepository {
  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;

  public List<ArticleBatch> findAll(String articleId) {
  Query nativeQuery =  em.createNativeQuery(loadQuery("/db/queries/articles/BatchByWarehouse.sql"), ArticleBatch.class);
    nativeQuery.setParameter(1, articleId);
    return (List<ArticleBatch>) nativeQuery.getResultList();
  }

  private String loadQuery(String path) {
    try {
      InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
      java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
      return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Failed to load query {}: {}", path, e.getMessage(), e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a sql file but Spring Data JPA will look in `/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties`
to find named queries, which allows you to specify queries in a sql file.

This is described in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662013/66686).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [repository](https://github.com/mcanatalay/spring-jpa-resource-query).

You need to provide a `JpaQueryMethodFactory` bean to your configuration. You can extend the `JpaQueryMethod` class and override the `getAnnotatedQuery` and `getRequiredAnnotatedQuery` functions to read queries from the file.